# Julia: delete rows and columns from an array or matix

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

How can I delete one or more rows and/or columns from an array?

Answer (score 10):

Working with:

```
julia> array = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16]
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4
  5   6   7   8
  9  10  11  12
 13  14  15  16
```

To delete a single row (here row 2):

```
julia> newarray = array[1:end .!= 2, :]
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4
  9  10  11  12
 13  14  15  16
```

To delete a single column (here column 3):

```
julia> newarray = array[:, 1:end .!= 3]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   4
  5   6   8
  9  10  12
 13  14  16
```

To delete a single row and a single column (here row 2, column 3):

```
julia> newarray = array[1:end .!= 3, 1:end .!= 3]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   4
  5   6   8
 13  14  16
```

To delete multiple rows (here rows 2, 4):

```
julia> newarray = array[setdiff(1:end, (2,4)), :]
2×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1   2   3   4
 9  10  11  12
```

To delete multiple columns (here columns 2, 4):

```
julia> newarray = array[:, setdiff(1:end, (2,4))]
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   3
  5   7
  9  11
 13  15
```

To delete a single row and multiple columns (here row 4 and columns 3, 4):

```
julia> newarray = array[1:end .!= 4, setdiff(1:end, (3,4))]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1   2
 5   6
 9  10

# or

julia> newarray = array[setdiff(1:end, 4), setdiff(1:end, (3,4))]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1   2
 5   6
 9  10

# or
julia> newarray = array[setdiff(1:end, (4,)), setdiff(1:end, (3,4))]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1   2
 5   6
 9  10
```

To delete multiple rows and columns (here rows 1, 2 and columns 3, 4):

```
julia> newarray = array[setdiff(1:end, (1,2)), setdiff(1:end, (3,4))]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  9  10
 13  14
```

Comment: This doesn't delete anything. Instead your creating copies.

Comment: That is true. One may replace the array with the edited array by changing `newarray` to `array` above.  This will create an edited "copy" and release the "original".

Comment: For a vector there is `deleteat!` which deletes without any copies.